# How set page number 2 of paging in table on start

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I try manually set start page of MudTable by using NavigateTo, but get no result.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender){
   await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender).ConfigureAwait(true);
   if(firstRender){
     table.NavigateTo(2);
    }
}
```

Reproduction link
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GkQbvkvcxNzoxxaq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this directly in your MudTable element :

```
<MudTable CurrentPage="2">
```

If you do this remove the lines you added in OnAfterRenderAsync.

You can find this in the [API doc](https://mudblazor.com/api/table#properties).

Also changing this :

```
table.NavigateTo(2);
```

To this :

```
table.CurrentPage = 2;
```

Seems to be working too, but setting it in the elements seems cleaner.

Comment: First suggest is helped.

Comment: "table.CurrentPage = 2" - doesn't work

Comment: Glad i could help. I've used your link and modified the code and it seems to work.